# How to get a warning in Release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Release Pipeline which do some stuffs. One of my tasks display warning but at task status i read 'succedeed' and also on release status level.

Whenever a warning is reported, i would like that task also be on warning state.
How can i achieve that ?
[image]

i also try some setting here
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which task are you using in your release pipeline?

Comment: Hi i used task 'Powershell v2'. Hope it can help to diagnose